# Search/filter functions work locally when testing, but not when deployed to gh-pages. No errors on console

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, progressive-web-apps, serverless-framework

App has a city search component as well as filtering number of events component that both work when testing at localhost, but when deployed to gh-pages the app doesn't behave as expected. The difference is while testing locally, I am using mock data, and when deployed the app pulls from an api. There are no errors in the console. My question is, why does this happen and what am I missing?

https://evandersloot.github.io/meet-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a typo in my api.js. I was concentrating on the components when I should have been looking at how the api was interacting, since all worked locally but not when deployed on gh-pages.